# Laravel 5 routing not working, .htaccess not loaded

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my Laravel project, I have been browsing some questions but they haven't solved my problem... So I have

- changed the httpd.conf AllowOverride to All
- enabled the rewrite module on Apache

but I still get a 404 error when trying to navigate to any other route than the root.

I added a redirect line to my .htaccess, but the pages never redirect, so that's where I infer that the .htaccess is not being loaded.

EDIT // Adding index.php to the URL works! So `localhost/laravel/crud4/public/index.php/create` works, but `localhost/laravel/crud4/public/create` does not.

Here's my .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.google.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here are my routes

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'DogsController@index']);
Route::get('/create', ['as' => 'create', 'uses' => 'DogsController@create']);
Route::resource('dogs', 'DogsController');
```

Only the first route works. What's the problem? I can give more information if it's needed.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. DId you get the answer?

Comment: I just move `root/public/.htaccess to root/.htaccess` and it works